error occurred when creating backup for milvus
Hello I'm a newbie in using milvus-backup tool
Milvus version: from 2.3.12
Deployment mode(standalone or cluster): cluster
milvus-backup version: v0.4.14
I tried to backup my collection in a remote instance of milvus to my local minio.
However, when I run the command:
./milvus-backup create -n test_backup
I get this error:
[2024/06/13 15:06:06.852 +08:00] [INFO] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:523] ["Begin copy data"] [dbName=default] [collectionName=chapters] [segmentNum=2]
[2024/06/13 15:06:06.852 +08:00] [DEBUG] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:531] ["copy segment"] [collection_id=444879892039202356] [partition_id=444879892039202357] [segment_id=444879892139483548] [group_id=0]
[2024/06/13 15:06:06.852 +08:00] [DEBUG] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:888] [insertPath] [bucket=a-bucket] [insertPath=files/insert_log/444879892039202356/444879892039202357/444879892139483548/]
[2024/06/13 15:06:06.853 +08:00] [ERROR] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:531] ["Fail to fill segment backup info"] [collection_id=444879892040221795] [partition_id=444879892040221796] [segment_id=444879892009040118] [group_id=0] [error="Get empty input path, but segment should not be empty, files/insert_log/444879892040221795/444879892040221796/444879892009040118/"] [stack="github.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup/core.(*BackupContext).backupCollectionExecute...]

Can anyone help me how I can fix this "error="Get empty input path, but segment should not be empty, "

This error typically occurs when the Milvus backup tool expects to find data files in the specified path but doesn't find any. Here are some possible ways I suggest you can try to troubleshoot this issue:

Verify Data in Milvus: Ensure the collection chapters contains data:

from pymilvus import connections, Collection
connections.connect(host='your-milvus-host', port='your-milvus-port')
collection = Collection('chapters')
print(f"Number of entities: {collection.num_entities}")


Check MinIO Configuration: Ensure the MinIO bucket is correctly configured and accessible:

mc ls myminio/a-bucket/files/insert_log/444879892040221795/444879892040221796/444879892009040118/  


Permissions and Access:
Verify Milvus backup tool has the necessary read/write permissions for the specified paths.

